# Get a field length in mysql for query

Tags: mysql, cakephp-1.2

I'm using cakephp 1.2, and I have this situation:
I have a table which has a 'class' field, where class can be 'A','B','C','G', or a string of three letters 'DBB','ABA', etc.
Every string has sense (for example, A = Article, B = Book, etc). 
I write this code:

```
if ($_GET['classificazione']!="art0")
{
    $classificazione=$_GET['classificazione'];
    if ($classificazione=="A"||$classificazione=="B"||$classificazione=="C"||$classificazione=="G")
                $conditions[]=array('classe =' => "$classificazione");
```

This is working for the 'one letter' case, but I don't know what to do with 2 or more letters.

 Since I don't care if they are equals ('DBB' and 'ABA' are both documents), I was thinking to check the length so I tried this:

```
else
    $conditions[]=array('LENGTH(classe) > 1'); }
```

I tested the else, and now it's working.

Comment: I am not sure but as far as i have understood, you need [CHAR_LENGTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

Comment: `if ($classificazione=="A"||
 $classificazione=="B"||
 $classificazione=="C"||
 $classificazione=="G"||
 $classificazione=="DBB" ||
 $classificazione== "ABA")` not doing your job?

Comment: @DoSparKot With the Else I put it's working. I think your it's ok, but I can have more then that 2 letters combination, so I need the most general case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LENGTH() for checking length in bytes:

```
SELECT str FROM sometable WHERE LENGTH(str) = 5;
```

Or CHAR_LENGTH() for checking length in number of characters (useful for multi-byte strings):

```
SELECT str FROM sometable WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(str) = 5;
```